# getElementById return Null but there is the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Hi I have 3 Drop Down List that I implemented with the `<select>` tag. At the first ddl I associeted the following javascript function

```
function aggiorna_provincia(tipo_pannello) {
    var objregione; 
    objregione = document.getElementById("<%=regione_residenzaIDropDownList.ClientID%>");
    id_regione = objregione.options[objregione.selectedIndex].value;

    if (id_regione != 0) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "../jquery/update1.aspx",
            type: "get",
            data: "cc=" + id_regione + "&tp=" + tipo_pannello,
            success: function (response) {
                $("#div_provinciaI").html(response);
                $("#<%=provincia_residenzaIDropDownList.ClientID%>").focus();
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("errore di connessione");
            }
        });
    }
    break;      
}
```

and the update1 page is

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim codice As Integer = Integer.Parse(Request.QueryString("cc").ToString())
    Dim tipo_pannello As Integer = Integer.Parse(Request.QueryString("tp").ToString())
    Dim regione As New List(Of regioni)

    Using db_antiriciclaggio As New db_antiriciclaggioEntities
        Try
            regione = (From tab_r In db_antiriciclaggio.regioni Where tab_r.IDNazione = codice Select tab_r).ToList()
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Using
     Response.Write("<div id='div_regioneI' style='text-align:left'>")
    Response.Write("<select id='regione_residenzaIDropDownList' runat='server' onchange='aggiorna_provincia(1)'>")

    If (regione.Count = 0) Then
        Response.Write("<option value='0'>Scegli prima lo stato</option>")
    Else
        Response.Write("<option value='0'>Scegli la regione</option>")
    End If
    For Each temp In regione
        Response.Write("<option value='" & temp.idregione & "'>" & temp.nomeregione & "</option>")
    Next

    Response.Write("</select>")
    Response.Write("</div>")
End Sub
```

But when I run the `aggiorna_provincia()` function (a similar function for updating the 3rd ddl) on the second ddl I obtain a null object when I try to find the ddl in the javascript function

Comment: Please create a [*reduced* test case](http://css-tricks.com/reduced-test-cases/) on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or a similar service so that we don't have to slog through unrelated code.

Comment: I think at jsfiddle but the code can't run because is a combination of Javascript and asp.net

Comment: The point is to *not* use ASP.NET, and show a demo of a small amount of the rendered output.

Comment: You can't write out server tags to the client like that. What does your rendered HTML look like?

Answer (score 0):

I guess "<%=regione_residenzaIDropDownList.ClientID%>" and 'regione_residenzaIDropDownList' are just not the same.

Btw: Your response.write(...) approach looks like it will make it hard to maintain your code. You should use more of the asp in the templates.

Comment: But they have the same id..or not?

Comment: one is just a string, the other one is a tag, which resolves to an id.